# Clou dataproc initialization actions - port assignments

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

We want to deploy a number of the applications into our cluster (Tez, Hue, Presto, Zeppelin and Oozie. A quick scan of the repo suggests that some of the ports will conflict by default (Zeppellin and Presto).

Is this a bug? How do I go about ensuring we can initialize the cluster with the tools we need ? Suggesting I have multiple clusters isn't really a useful answer.

Thanks

Comment: For posterity, the discussion/answer is here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/issues/159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per above:
For posterity, the discussion/answer is here: github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actio‌​ns/